# (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream on nginx

Tags: php, nginx

So I made an alternative domain to a site of mine, using nginx but that error keeps coming up.
The original site works just fine, but the alternate domain shows this error.

> 2021/01/04 15:14:27 [error] 2007#2007: *269 connect() failed (111:
> Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
> 35.209.169.6, server: cocknutsandball.com, request: "GET /sh4 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/sh4", host:
> "104.244.79.32"

Here is what I tried to do:

1. reload nginx and php8.0-fpm
2. disable any firewall

for the alternate domain
'''

```
server {
     listen 80;
         server_name cocknutsandball.com www.cocknutsandball.com;
         location / {
              proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
              proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
     }
}
```

'''

For the main domain that works

'''

```
server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/;
        index chat.php lang_en.php emoji.css;
        server_name ylwebs62zfllr4hhailwwysq2erzoxqcwqhfokkzimi73c2n4fp3mspad.o$
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi.conf;
        }
        error_log
        /root/error_log;
        access_log
        /root/access_log;
}
```

'''

OK quick update: I changed the config to be completely identical to the one for the working domain but change the domain so now it is:

```
server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:80;
        root /var/www/;
        index chat.php lang_en.php emoji.css;
        server_name cocknutsandball.com;
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi.conf;
        }
        error_log
        /root/error_log;
        access_log
        /root/access_log;
}
```

but now im getting the same exact error

just to clarify some things:

1. I have restarted nginx
2. i have made sure that the configuration syntax is working(which it was)
3. i have changed the index to another file to see if thats a problem
4. i made sure all of the ports are being listened to
5. i have but the domain into the original domain config, still the same error on the alternate domain
6. I have referred to the manual, and a lot of other guides on the internet, i just have a really difficult time understanding it

Comment: Is your php really listening port `9000` on `127.0.0.1`? PS: even if it did - you need to configure fastcgi, not http proxy. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/

Comment: @zerkms I have made an edit clarifying what i was doing, but to answer your question, yes it was, and i made sure that port was being listened to

Comment: @Sammitch just made another edit to clarify some more things that i should've made clearer

Comment: It's not clear what your problem now is. The second sample looks correct, the first sample tries to forward http requests to fastcgi.

Comment: @zerkms which is what kinda shocks me, like the syntax is fine, everything is running just fine and listening just fine, so idk whats going on unless there's something i didn't check

Comment: The syntax is not fine: php is not an http proxy.

Comment: ok im kind of new to nginx so my question would be, whats the best way to fix that?

Comment: @Sammitch alright so, i basically remade the entire config to be identical to the one that works but that one is still giving me the same error even though like i said, they are identical. The other one still works just fine

Comment: The "corrected" config may not give you the same error. You probable have modified the wrong config file or has not restarted nginx.

Comment: looked at both, correct config file and nginx restarted